# Checkbox Value is reversed based on data that user enters, JavaScript needs to know when it is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, velocity

Good Evening,

I have a scenario where users are checking a box to enter a row of data (or update a row of data) in a MySQL database via SparkJava/ Java. Everything is working as expected except for one little issue.

If a value already exists in the database the Checkbox is the opposite of what it should be. So for example... The first time a user clicks the checkbox, it will add it to the database. However if you refresh the page it will try adding it again instead of removing it.

I am almost certain the problem is with the following line:

```
var newValue = $(this).is(':checked') ? "add" : "remove";
```

But I am not sure how to make the JavaScript know if the value was checked already. Note that I am already doing this check with a conditional statement through Velocity in my HTML (this functionality works as expected).

```
#if ($amiibo.Collected == "Y")
<div class="star has-text-warning" id="star$amiibo.AmiiboID">
#else
<div class="star" id="star$amiibo.AmiiboID">
#end
```

Below is the full snippet from my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".mine" ).change(function() {

     var newValue = $(this).is(':checked') ? "add" : "remove";

        var amiibo = $(this).attr('id');
        var activeAmiiboID = amiibo.split('#')[1];
        var activeAmiiboName = amiibo.split('#')[2];
        $("#star"+activeAmiiboID).toggleClass("has-text-warning");
        console.log( "Handler for .change() called with value: " + newValue );
        console.log("activeAmiiboID is: "+ activeAmiiboID);
        console.log("Sending request to backend");
        if (newValue == 'add') {
            VanillaToasts.create({
                title: 'Added to Favorites',
                text: activeAmiiboName + ' has been added to your Collection.',
                timeout: 4000,
                type: 'success',
            });
        }
        else if (newValue == 'remove') {
            VanillaToasts.create({
                title: 'Removed from Favorites',
                text: activeAmiiboName + ' has been removed from your Collection.',
                timeout: 4000,
                type: 'error',
            });
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: '/collection',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                mine: newValue + "Amiibo",
                amiiboID: activeAmiiboID
            },
            success: function () {
                console.log("Request completed successfully");
            }
        });
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Is there either...

A) A way to make the javascript know this value is checked based on my conditional statement in velocity or 
B) Another reasonable way to make the Javascript know this value is checked

Thank you!
Travis W.

Comment: What about the HTMLElement.dataset api? You can add an attribute to the input (the dataset api allows you to do so in a way guaranteed not to cause compatibility problems later as elements have new attributes made legal) 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured this one out. I am running a new variable addRemove through an if statement before letting the JS decide to add or remove. Still open to other ideas! Always open to learning. Below is the solution I have tested and it is working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".mine" ).change(function() {

        var amiibo = $(this).attr('id');
        var activeAmiiboID = amiibo.split('#')[1];
        var activeAmiiboName = amiibo.split('#')[2]
        var addRemove = document.getElementById("mine#"+activeAmiiboID+"#"+activeAmiiboName).value;

        if (addRemove == 'Y') {
            console.log("If: Value was "+ addRemove);
            var newValue = $(this).is(':checked') ? "remove" : "add";

        } else {
            console.log("Else: Value was "+ addRemove);
            var newValue = $(this).is(':checked') ? "add" : "remove";
        }

        $("#star"+activeAmiiboID).toggleClass("has-text-warning");
        console.log( "Handler for .change() called with value: " + newValue );
        console.log("activeAmiiboID is: "+ activeAmiiboID);
        console.log("Sending request to backend");
        if (newValue == 'add') {
            VanillaToasts.create({
                title: 'Added to Favorites',
                text: activeAmiiboName + ' has been added to your Collection.',
                timeout: 4000,
                type: 'success',
            });
        }
        else if (newValue == 'remove') {
            VanillaToasts.create({
                title: 'Removed from Favorites',
                text: activeAmiiboName + ' has been removed from your Collection.',
                timeout: 4000,
                type: 'error',
            });
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: '/collection',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                mine: newValue + "Amiibo",
                amiiboID: activeAmiiboID
            },
            success: function () {
                console.log("Request completed successfully");
            }
        });
    });
```